# How to install package offline?

Tags: networking, internet, offline

On my Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS network-manager isn't installed yet. Without this program I can't connect to WiFi network. But I can't install this package from Ubuntu without network connection. Here is my question. How to install this offline? or How to install from another computer?

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to WiFi without network-manager (even though it should have been installed by default). Open a terminal and run:

`sudo iwconfig`

There will be some output like `lo, eth0, wlan0`. The one we want is `wlan`. Take note of its name (probably wlan0).

`sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`

Go to the end of the file and create a new line. Write the following:

`auto wlan0`

Replacing wlan0 with what you found back there. In new lines:

`iface wlan0 inet dhcp`

`wpa-ssid SSID`

Replacing `SSID` with the name of your WiFi connection.

`wpa-psk password`

Replacing `password` with your WiFi network's password.

Hit Ctrl+O then Enter to save and Ctrl+X to exit. In the terminal, run:

`sudo ifup wlan0`

And you should be connected. You can now install network-manager and anything you want. Remember to remove everything you wrote from /etc/network/interfaces before using network-manager otherwise it won't work.

Comment: A `sudo iwconfig` command doesn't works. Command not found.

Comment: You did something wrong. Try `sudo ifconfig` instead.

Comment: Command workd, but not internet. My `/etc/network/interface/` looks like this (without #): `auto lo` (new line) `iface lo inet loopback` (3 lines down) `allow-hotplug eth0` (new line) `iface eth0 inet dhcp` (new line) `auto wlan0` (new line) `iface wlan0 inet dhcp` (new line) `wpa-ssid` (ssid) (new line) `wpa-psk` (password). And information for `sudo ifconfig` is: eth0, lo. I don't know what I have to do.

Comment: If ifconfig shows only lo and eth0, your Wireless driver is not working/doesn't exist. Could you run `dmesg | grep Network` and give me the output?

Comment: Also try `dmesg | grep Wireless`.

Comment: My `ifconfig` show wlan0.

Comment: But.. You just said it doesn't! OK, could you remove everything you added to /etc/network/interfaces and reinstall network-manager? You know, that should work out of the box.

Comment: My `ifconfig` show wlan0. `dmesg` command show a lot of text.

Comment: I don't have network-manager (ubuntu said that).

Comment: How to shutdown system with command?

Comment: I can't do some actions, beacuse it's only Raspberry Pi.

Comment: You definitely should have said that in your question. Shutdown=`sudo shutdown -h now`